# Will .net core create a new session each time i send a request to a web API?

Tags: .net

I have created one .net core SPA (Angular) web application, so my doubt is will this application create a new session each time I send a get or post request to a method in API controller, or will it just create a single session when I initially request for the client application.

I asked this doubt because I have to set the Identity claims in my application, So I came with the confusion that, do I need to set the Identity each time when I send a get or post request, Or do I just need to set the Identity claims only once the application is started (that is when user load the base Url, login page for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are not used in Dotnet core web API unless you configure to do so.

As for reusing sessions (In case you configure to use sessions), It will reuse the existing session as long as you send the session cookies you received on the first request in the next request.

The practice for Authentication on web API is usually we configure JWT and pass the token in header of every request. You can find many examples of setting tokens in headers with the use of interceptors in Angular application over google.